# How to add the town name to the conky Harmattan configuration?

Tags: customization, conky

The conky configuration [Harmattan](http://zagortenay333.deviantart.com/art/Conky-Harmattan-426662366) displays information about the current state of the weather but it does not display the name of the city that the weather refers to.

How can I add the name of the city as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the `~/.conkyrc` file. This is a hidden file in your home directory. You can see the hidden files by hitting `Ctrl+H`.

In this file, find a line that says

```
# The "conditions" section of the conky #
```

3 lines below the above line, there's a line beginning with

```
${goto 46}${voffset 14}${font Droid Sans :size=12}
```

We will use this line later.

Make a new text file using your favorite text editor and add the following in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep "yweather:location" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "city=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" |tr -d '\n' && echo -n " - " && grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "text=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"
```

Save the file in your home folder. I saved it in `~/.conky-weather/town_descr`. Remember to  mark it as executable by going to Properties->Permissions->Execute file as program.

Then go back to that line you've found into `~/.conkyrc` and edit it to be like this:

```
${goto 46}${voffset 14}${font Droid Sans :size=11}${color1}${execi 300 ~/.conky-weather/town_descr}${font}${color}
```

Notice we've reduced the font side to 11 because now the town name will be displayed as well and we need more space.

Result:

[image: conky result]

Notice the "**Patra** - Partly Cloudy"